# owl-carousel не получается на одной странице разместить N количество каруселей

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть галерея в ней на одной странице допустим 8 штук изображений, кликая на изображение появляется модальное окно и в нем есть еще ряд изображений организованные с помощью карусели. В чем проблема, когда есть одна карусель в коде на странице, то все нормально работает, а вот если такая карусель и в другом месте на той же странице используется то все перестает работать. Я понимаю что использует одни id, это что получается сколько раз я ее использую это столько раз нужно менять id и переписывать js возможно ли другой вариант? Я так понял, что нужно пробежаться страницей скриптом и присвоить id уникальный от 1 до ~ а потом чтоб он разбил на четные и нечетные и присваивал нечетные переменной sync1 а четные sync2 но как это реализовать уму не прилажу... Может подскажете альтернативу, либо карусели либо решению то что предложил.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sync1 = $("#sync1");
  var sync2 = $("#sync2");

  sync1.owlCarousel({
    singleItem: true,
    slideSpeed: 1000,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: false,
    afterAction: syncPosition,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
  });

  sync2.owlCarousel({
    items: 15,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 10],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 10],
    itemsTablet: [768, 8],
    itemsMobile: [479, 4],
    pagination: false,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 100,
    afterInit: function(el) {
      el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
    }
  });

  function syncPosition(el) {
    var current = this.currentItem;
    $("#sync2")
      .find(".owl-item")
      .removeClass("synced")
      .eq(current)
      .addClass("synced")
    if ($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined) {
      center(current)
    }
  }

  $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo", number);
  });

  function center(number) {
    var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
    var num = number;
    var found = false;
    for (var i in sync2visible) {
      if (num === sync2visible[i]) {
        var found = true;
      }
    }

    if (found === false) {
      if (num > sync2visible[sync2visible.length - 1]) {
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length + 2)
      } else {
        if (num - 1 === -1) {
          num = 0;
        }
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
      }
    } else if (num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length - 1]) {
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
    } else if (num === sync2visible[0]) {
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - 1)
    }

  }

});
```

```css
#sync1 .item {
  background: #0c83e7;
  padding: 80px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
#sync2 .item {
  background: #C9C9C9;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sync2 .item h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
#sync2 .synced .item {
  background: #0c83e7;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: если возможно, должно помочь обращение к слайдерам не через `id`, а через `class` как-то так: `$(".carousel_name").each(function(){     $(this).owlCarousel();  });`

Comment: @lexxl хорошо как это решит проблему запуска 8 каруселей на странице?

Comment: не надо будет обращаться по уникальным id для активации слайдера

Comment: @lexxl спасибо, попробую, я еще одну альтернативу нашел это fotorama, вот [ссылка](http://fotorama.io/). Тут уже все реализовано, хотя мне каруселька больше по душе.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите инициализировать карусель несколько раз, вы можете сделать это по классу, также если вы хотите сохранить ссылки на инстансы каруселей для дальнейшей работы с ними, вы можете написать что-то вроде

```
var Carusels = [];
$('.carusel').each(function (index, elem) {
    Carusels.push($(elem).owlCarousel({ ... }));     
});
```

Comment: это получается что в место многоточия я вставляю то что находилось в `$(document).ready(function() { ...... }` скрипта. Правильно я понял вас?

Comment: Нет. То что вы вставляете при инициализации слайдера. Объект с параметрами